# How many solutions does this equation have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is: how many solutions does this equation have? 
$$\frac {2x^3+1.6x}{x^2-1} = 7$$

I don't even have a clue how to approach this...

Comment: As a consequence of this equation we get a polynomial one, if you multiply both sides by the denominator.

Comment: Is the coefficient of $x$ 1.6 as in 16/10?

Comment: For an interesting read, see [this pdf](http://ms.yccd.edu/Data/Sites/1/userfiles/facstaff/jthoo/cvandpubs/papers/numrealrootscubic.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2x^3+1.6x}{x^2-1}=7$$
$$\frac{2x^3+1.6x}{x^2-1}(x^2-1)=7(x^2-1)$$
$$2x^3+1.6x=7x^2-7$$
$$2x^3-7x^2+1.6x+7=0$$
You are now left with a polynomial equation of degree three - a cubic, in the form of $ax^3+bx^2+cd+d=0$. All you have to do is [find the roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots). This isn't a special case, unfortunately, so we have to do it the long way. A root $x_k$ is
$$x_k=-\frac{1}{3a}\left(b+u_kC+\frac{\Delta_0}{u_kC}\right)$$
where
$$u_1=1, u_2=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}, u_3=\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$C=\sqrt[3]{\frac{\Delta_1\sqrt{\Delta_1^2-4\Delta_0^3}}{2}}$$
Additionally,
$$\Delta_0=b^2-3ac, \Delta_1=2b^3-9abc+27a^2d$$
I leave you to calculate $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, and the associated quantities. The algebra should be simply enough from there.

Comment: Yeah....I think the equation is $2x^3-7x^2+1.6x+7=0$

Comment: @G-man Whoops, thanks.

Comment: Clear fractions, get cubic polynomial, with positive discriminant, so 3 real roots.

Comment: @jbuddenh Yes, that's another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem simplifies to $2x^3-7x^2+1.6x+7=0$.

Notice that you have one $x$ value raised to the power of $3$. This means you have $3$ solutions. With a vertical shift, you have $3$ real solutions.

Comment: As [G-man said](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415984/how-many-solutions-does-this-equation-have/1415995#comment2885147_1415995), it's $+7$. We both made the same error.

Comment: Haha thanks, just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {2x^3+1.6x}{x^2-1} = 7$$
$$2x^3+1.6x-7x^2+7 = 0$$
$$20x^3+16x-70x^2+70 = 0$$
$$10x^3-35x^2+8x+35 = 0$$
eliminate the quadratic term by substituting $x=y+7/6$